# How to add additional column relationship in pivot table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

Version: Laravel 5.4

I have 3 Models

Model: Employee

```php
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function emails(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email')->using('App\EmailEmployee');
    }
```

Model: Email

```php
    protected $fillable = ['username'];
    public function employees(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Employee')->using('App\EmailEmployee');
    }
```

Every Employee has many email access and emails allocates to many employees. But I have another column in `email_employee` table

```
email_id                    (emails table)
employee_id                 (employees table)
assigned_by                 (employees table)
```

how to make relation of `assigned_by` column with `employees table`

Pivot Model

```php
    use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
    class EmailEmployee extends Pivot{
        public function assignedBy(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
        }
    }
```

I tried

```php
    $email = Email::find(1);
    dd($email->employee[0]->pivot->assignedBy);
```

But not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Custom Intermediate Table Model

To solve your problem, you should look to use the `->using()` method on the `belongsToMany` method.

The subsection "Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models" in this link briefly describes this. [eloquent-relationships#many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

You basically create a model for the pivot table so that you can define additional relations to it.

You can still access data from Blade and Controllers the way you are now as Laravel will still deal with the relationship for you. However, you can access the pivot table with `->pivot` and as you have told laravel to use a model for the pivot table, you can also access all the relationship defined functions from that model.

Example:

> Employee

```
class Employee extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function emails(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email')
        ->using('App\PivotModel');
    }
}
```

> Email

```
 class Email extends Model
    {
    protected $fillable = ['username'];
        public function employees(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Employee')
            ->using('App\PivotModel');
        }
    }
```

> PivotModel

```
class EmailEmployee extends Pivot
{
    public function assignedBy(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee','assigned_by');
        }
}
```

**Be Sure to extend Pivot on the pivot model and not Model**

Now you can just do:

```
$user->emails()->first()->pivot->assignedBy
```

The reason for the ->first() is that you have a many to many, meaning that you will be getting a collection of emails assigned to the user. You would normally loop through them but for this example, simply selecting the first will do the same.

If you just want the column value and not the relationship value, then add `->withPivot('assigned_by')` which will allow you to access the value directly.

If you are wanting to audit when the assignment was made, then you may also want to add `->withTimestamps()` if your pivot table has timestamps included, so that you can access those too.

Comment: Strange, I have this working on my application. What errors do you get, or what is not working?

Comment: your code almost correct but i have reference of Employee model on `assigned_by `and i have not `employee_id` which laravel takes default. see i have put my answer....and thanks

Comment: Thats correct..because I have differ column name than laravel default column named `employee_id` if not specified....

Answer (score 1):

Changes in Pivot model

Pivot Model

```php
    use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
    class EmailEmployee extends Pivot{
        public function assignedBy(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee','assigned_by');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an custom pivot model

EmailEmployee

```php
class EmailEmployee extends Pivot
{
    public function giver()
    {
        return  $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

Employee

```php
class Employee extends Model
{
    public function emails(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email')->using('App\EmailEmployee');
    }
}
```

Email

```php
class Email extends Model
{
    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Employee')->using('App\EmailEmployee');
    }
}
```

So  you can access `giver` by $email->pivot->giver;

Comment: It's from laravel 5.8 https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models. Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: bangnokia, you are trying to get the value of a pivot table that has not yet been accessed in your example. The pivot would be on the user linked with the emails not just the emails. So $email->employees->first()->pivot->giver

Comment: I am using laravel 5.4